# Can Unity WWW http requests scape from the capturing by tools like httpscoop or Charles?

Tags: ios, http, web, unity-game-engine

I do several WWW http requests in my app but only capture one of them by "httpscoop".

envir: Unity 4.7.2f

device: iphone5s

My app is already uploaded to appstore , and is ready for install.

I'm sure that the requests all succeed because if not the app will stop.

My code is below as simple:

new WWW("http://192.168.0.1/android/version.txt");

This issue appears only on part of the ios device. It seems that the WWW request did not do http request but only return the cached data.When I delete the app and reinstall it , the issue would be fixed.So it's hard to rebuild the issue.

My question is ,
Is there some condition that WWW http request would not do the http request but only return the cached data?(I also checked the http server and did't receive the excepted requests)
Or Give me some directions to figure it out.

Any help will be appreciative.

Comment: Did you tried using UnityWebRequest ? The new UnityWebRequest is already binded with functions like caching and also have POST , GET methods and more .
http://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

Comment: You need to update your Unity to at least 5

Comment: No, because our app has already published to appstore so I hope to figure it out without update the app version.And WWW worked just fine before now.

Comment: My confusion is why and how WWW can complete a request without any network operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Its already all display in manual / scripting . Please make sure next time you ask question after reading the documentation .

```
// In IEnumerator
var www = new WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("link");
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html

Comment: Thank you , but I do read the documentation , I used WWW(url) for the txt file and WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("link") for assetbundle.

Comment: And it works fine before I update the app version recently.Now what confuse me is that why I cannot monitor the www request from file server?